Theorem of highest weight of semisimple Lie algebras: what fails precisely for reductive case
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ a complex semisimple Lie algebra. It is well known that by the theorem of the highest weight, all finite-dimensional complex irreps of $\mathfrak{g}$ are (up to iso) classified by dominant integral weights $\alpha \in \mathfrak{h}^*$ (ie those integral weights lying in the cone spanned by fundamental weights). That's classical, concrete constructions can be found for instance in Humphreys' or Hall's introductions to representation theory & (semisimple)Lie algebras.
Question: Where precisely the dominant integral weights construction described in quoted sources for semisimple Lie groups (... and leading to an integral cone where all weights representing irreps sit) would break down "irreparably" (...and probably causes "nonsense" results) if we would start naively with a reductive Lie group instead (ie having nontrivial center $\mathfrak{z}$) and would mimic stubbornly the construction for semisimple case?
I would like to note that it is familar to me that an educated approach would be based on considering decomposing
$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{s} \oplus \mathfrak{a}$ into abelian and  semisimple part and treat reps of both parts separately.
But that's not what I want to discuss in this question. I would like to chew through the construction in order to understand where (ie at which intermediate steps) exactly the dominant weights construction (and it's connection to irreps) for semisimple Lie algebra  badly fail (and to which extend? Maybe this would give a hint to a partial result) if we apply would "with head trough the wall" perform the semisimple construction to reductive algebra.
Let's see: Firstly, we have in reductive setting still the root decomposition of the Lie algebra as $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in R}\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha}$ under adjoint representation by maximal Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ which contains the center $\mathfrak{z}$ where $R$ are the roots.
We can still fix positive roots and obtain inclusion $R_s \subset R_+ \subset R \subset \mathfrak{h}^*$ of simple and positive roots.
Here appear first differences in contrast to semisimple case: $R$ not span (as vector space) the whole $\mathfrak{h}^*$ but a subspace of dimension which equals to cardinality of the set of simple elements $|R_s|$ which in turn equals to the semisimple rank defined as $\dim \mathfrak{h}/\mathfrak{z}$.
Note that the Killing form $K(,)$on $\mathfrak{h}$ which induces nondegenerate form on $\mathfrak{h}/\mathfrak{z}$ (indeed only the center makes it degenerated) and thus induces a bilinear form on the dual spaces $K^*(,)$ gives us still a way to to declare dominant weights (whose elements in $h \in \mathfrak{h}^*$ with $K^*(h,r) \ge 0$ for all positive roots $r \in R_+$.
In contrast in the construction of fundamental weights there would be more involved in terms of non-canonical choices:
Indeed, recall in case with  $\mathfrak{g}$ semisimple, let $r_1,..., r_d \in R_s$ be the simple roots, there exist for each $r_i$ a unique $b_i \in \mathfrak{h}^*$ - a fundamental weight - satisfying $K^*(b_i,r_j)=\delta_{ij}$ (maybe the Killing form should have been normed somewhere in a previous step).
What changes if $\mathfrak{g}$ is not semisimple but reductive in the constructio ? If I'm not missing something, only that the fundamental weights are not not more uniquely determined but uniquely modulo $\mathfrak{z}^*$ as $\mathfrak{z}^*$ forms exactly the radical of induced Killing form on the dual of the Cartan space, right? And that's it, or is the story a bit longer?
Having once made these choices for the fundamental weights $z_i$, the story should continue similarly as in semisimple case: They span a cone and intersecting this cone with space of dominant weights gives us dominant integral weights which should witness as highest weights the irreps (...at least that's what the construction in semisimple case would be about).
The only problem I see so far is that these span not a full cone, ie it's topological dimension is due to rank defect smaller then dimension of $\mathfrak{h}^*$, it's a kind of "degenerated" cone.
What can we do at this stage? Can we for example complement these chosen fundamental weights $b_i$ by a basis from $\mathfrak{z}^*$ and then build (now nondegenerate cone)?
If that latter step not works, we have still our degenerated cone spanned by "chosen modulo $\mathfrak{z}$ unique" fundamental weights intersected with dominant weights.
Still, to which irreps of $\mathfrak{g}$ these would correspond, even if due to these obstructions we probably cannot expect a one-to-one correspondence between isomorphism classes of irreps and highest integral weights living in this cone?
Firstly, are there even more problems in this naive attempt to mimic the (first part of the) highest weight construction to reductive Lie algebras?
And still if we stay at the end of the day with this "degenerated cone": To which irreps are integral weights there correspond?

There is no failure; it's just that there are more dominant weights than the semisimple case suggests.  For example, all weights of (the Lie algebra of) a torus are dominant.  So you no longer have a cone (well, maybe, depending on your definition of a cone), but a space that is allowed to extend ‘bidirectionally’ in the central directions.  But all this is probably overkill, because a representation of $\mathfrak g$ is completely determined by what it does on the derived subalgebra $\mathfrak g'$, which is semisimple, and on the central Cartan subalgebra, which can do whatever it likes.

@LSpice: just to clarify your argument why a torus  - more precisely it's Lie algebra which equals to it's Cartan sub-Liealgebra - consists of dominant weights. Dominant weights $h \in \mathfrak{h}^$ are characterized by condition $K^(h,r) \ge 0$ ( where $K^*(,)$ is induced Killing to dual space) for $r \in R_+$ simple ( or equivalently by linearity positive) roots. But for a torus there are no roots, that's the joke, right?

@LSpice: (on second part) yes right, that's the consequence of decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}' \oplus \mathfrak{z}$  where for left semisimple summand we can apply the highest weight theory and right is abelian, that's determined by characters.

But the point is "which information" does carry the "cone" constucted "by brute force mimic" above (see from "In contrast in the construction of..." paragraph) which is spaned by "non unique" fundamental weights (constructed above more precsely by choices modulo $\mathfrak{z}^$ due to the presense of nontrivial center)? Is it just up rotation equivalnt to fundamental cone of $\mathfrak{g}'$ and that's it? (so no additional interesting things? Especially "how" it sits inside $\mathfrak{h}^$ and so? Note that naively thinking that might be potentially interesting from viewpoint of integrality

of resulting dominant integral weights "how" it is rotated). Or is there really no " new" issue going on?

There's no canonical inner product on $\mathfrak t^$, so it's hard to make sense of rotations, and the fundamental cone for $\mathfrak g'$ lives in $\mathfrak t^{\prime}$, which is a quotient of $\mathfrak t^$, so that it's hard to know what it would mean to rotate the fundamental cone for $\mathfrak g'$ in $\mathfrak t^$ anyway.  I think that the best that one can say is that the cone that you've constructed is a lift to $\mathfrak t^*$ of the fundamental cone for $\mathfrak g'$.

@LSpice: ah alright, I see (probably). So on Cartan algebra $\mathfrak{t}$ clearly there is an inner form (= restriction of Killing form), it cannot be "transfered" to dual $\mathfrak{t}^$, simply from elementary reason, because if we have a fin vector space $V$ with bilinear form $b$, then to transfer the bf to dual $V^$ we need to specify an iso $V \cong V^$, an that is nebel canonical as depends on base choice. That's the whole reason we have no canon inner product on dual $\mathfrak{t}^$, right?

But then, what do you mean in the example above with torus by "dominant" weights? Doesn't the term "dominant" require some positivity conditioned formulated in terms of an inequality expressed with an inner product (and weight live intrinsically in the dual space)?

No, it is a positivity condition on the pairing between the dual and the Lie algebra (weight evaluated on coroot).  We sometimes forget this in the semisimple case, where it's OK because of the canonical pairing that makes roots a positive multiple of coroots.

Also, there is no canonical inner form on $\mathfrak t$, because the Killing form on a non-semisimple reductive Lie algebra is not definite.  (The centre pairs trivially with everything.)  Again, it's good for questions about reductive groups to test how things would work for (Lie algebras of) tori.  If there were such a form, then it would serve itself as an isomorphism of $\mathfrak t$ with $\mathfrak t^*$, and we'd be able to transfer the inner product over that way.

@LSpice: unfortunately I'm still stuck at the positivity codition on the pairing of dual and Lie algebra for the case of Lie algebra of a torus. As you wrote this condition is induced by evaluation of weights on coroots. But a stupid question: How are in this context the "coroots" defined? Don't we need an inner form (especially nondegenerated) on the space to declare what a "coroot" (wrt given roots) is? But the space is exactly the opposite to semisimple, so we haven't such inner form. How we then could else talk about "coroots" in this example? Or do I confusing something at this stage?

The coroots of a reductive Lie algebra are the coroots of its semisimple part.  (One may define them directly, but it easily boils down to this.)  This makes sense because coroots ‘are’ elements of the Lie algebra, and $\mathfrak t'$ is a subspace, not a quotient, of $\mathfrak t$.  Thus, for (the Lie algebra of) a torus, there are no coroots.

@LSpice: When you write "One may define them "directly", to which procedure are you refering there? Via restricting to semisimple part is clear,(as is it forms direct summand) where we have this inner form, but what you mean by the "direct" method?

Re, there is, for each root $a$, a unique element $H_a$ of $\mathfrak t'$ such that $a(H_a) = 2$, and the reflection $x \mapsto x - x(H_a)a$ on $\mathfrak t^{\prime*}$ preserves the (restrictions to $\mathfrak t'$ of the) roots.  This forces $\mathfrak t'$ into the definition, so may reasonably be argued not to be a direct definition that reduces to the semisimple case but simply reduction to the semisimple case by definition.  But it does not rely on any choice of inner product.
